# Findbugs "Method May Fail to Close Stream" when using getResourceAsStream

Tags: java, tomcat, findbugs

If I have the following code in a servlet:

```
Properties p = new Properties();
p.load(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/test.properties"));
```

If I run the servlet through FindBugs, I would expect to get the warning [OS_OPEN_STREAM](http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/bugDescriptions.html#OS_OPEN_STREAM), but I don't. If I use a similar approach to open an arbitrary file on the filesystem (ie not in the classpath), I get the Findbugs warning as expected:

```
Properties p = new Properties();
p.load(new FileInputStream(new File("c:/test.properties")));
```

In the first example, is the warning absent because Findbugs is missing a valid warning (ie I should be closing the stream in a finally block after loading into the Properties object) or is there a reason I don't need to close the stream?

Thanks

Rich

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Look at the description of the warning:

> The method creates an IO stream
>   object, does not assign it to any
>   fields...

In your first case, your code does not *create* the stream, it asks the classloader to give it a stream. Thus, Findbugs does not consider your code responsible for closing the stream, probably to avoid false positives.

Note that a classloader could implement `getResourceAsStream()` in a way that does not require the stream to be closed (i.e. by copying the resource into memory and returning a `ByteArrayInputStream`). But for the common case of an `URLClassLoader` loading classes from a directory, closing the stream is indeed necessary to avoid leaking file handles.

Comment: I believe it's just an oversight on findbug's part. Close the stream.